# Magento 1.9 how to set products to out of stock if quantity is 0 using php?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cron, out-of-stock

The website I am currently working on has a bug where it will not update the in stock status to out of stock when the quantity is zero.

Importing a product that has zero quantity and then a reindex does not work.

I have also done an SSH reindex and rebuild the tables using the shell indexer.php.

Editing the product in the inventory tab of a product to set the quantity to zero will set the product to out of stock.

I need a way to use php and cron to do this every couple of hours to compensate for this error.

I found this code on the net and have tested it before and made it work but now it no longer works:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('cataloginventory/stock_item_collection');
    $outQty = Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/item/options_min_qty');
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('qty', array('gt' => $outQty));
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 0);
    foreach($collection as $item) {
        $item->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
    }
    $collection->save();
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('block_html');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: whats mean "it works but now it no longer works"? Something had to change.

Comment: Stupid me.  Forgot to include the app/Mage.php before this code.  Maybe I should just delete this question.

Comment: ah! Dont delete question, just add new post and select it as solution ;) It may be helpful for others